# "ever seen" vs. "ever been"

Tags: meaning

I know "have been somewhere" means "I went to somewhere", and the action happened at an unknown time in the past. I just want to know if "have seen" means "have been" sometimes?

Does this sentence literally ask if I "have seen"?

> Have you ever seen the Grand Canyon?

If I answer "I have seen Grand Canyon through internet", does it sound like a joke?

Comment: It asks if you have ever been there and seen it for real. The answer would be "Only in pictures," "Only on the Internet" etc. - not a joke, just a fact.